# urllib urlopen() errno 21 is a directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

The code I'm working with require a URL for a certain data directory, of which it opens using `urllib.urlopen()`. The samples provided use an url of a directory on a web server. However, when I try to enter an URL to a local directory via "file://.." urlopen throws the following:

> IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory:

I am wondering why urlopen can handle a directory link as http, but cannot handle a local directory link?

Comment: You have other standard functions that will do that...

Comment: It's up to the web server what a directory URL means. Some servers may provide a file listing of that directory, others will provide an index page, others still will give an error.